# Pushing two unique objects to an empty array results in an array with 2 equivalent objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reference

I have the following:

```
var params = {status: [69,71]};

var getTasks = function(params) {
    if (params.status.constructor === Array) {
        var statuses = params.status;
        var newParams = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < statuses.length; i++) {
            params.status = statuses[i];
            newParams.push(params);
        }
        console.log(newParams);

    }
    // else {
    //     ...
    // }
};
```

Calling `getTasks(params)` logs `newParams` as:

`[ { status: 71 }, { status: 71 } ]`.

I would expect this to log out

`[ { status: 69 }, { status: 71 } ]`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Inside your loop you're changing your global `params` object with `params.status = statuses[i];` and then you keep `push`ing the same `params` object. Objects are treated as reference, which means when you make changes to the object they'll propagate everywhere the object is referenced. That's how they get the same value, they're the same object. It's unclear what you're actually hoping to accomplish based on your code though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newParams.push(params);` is pushing the object referenced by `params` to your array. You have an array full of references to the same object, any modifications to that object will be present in each of the array elements, since they are all the same object. Create a new object each time instead of reusing the same one:

```
for (var i = 0; i < statuses.length; i++) {
    newParams.push( { status: statuses[i] } );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're pushing the same *Object* twice, the most recent change to the *Object* is visible.

```
var obj;
for (var i = 0; i < statuses.length; i++) {
    // construct obj as desired
    obj = {}; // notice this new object is created inside the loop
    obj.status = statuses[i];
    // push to your array
    newParams.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`params` is a *single object*. Inside of your `for` loop, by doing the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < statuses.length; i++) {
    params.status = statuses[i];
    newParams.push(params);
}
```

... you are overwriting the `status` field and pushing the object into the `newParams` array. However, the object isn't copied - instead, a *reference* to it is appended to the array. Thus, all elements of `newParams` are actually the same element.

Essentially, you need to push a *clone* of the params object into the array in the loop. If you're using jQuery or underscore, an easy way to clone is using the `extend()` function:

```
// jQuery
newParams.push(jQuery.extend({}, params));
// or Underscore
newParams.push(_.extend({}, params));
```

Answer (score 1):

@PaulPro and @PaulS gave correct answers, but there's always an opportunity to learn something new. In this case, I'd recommend to take a look at [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which can greatly simplify your code:

```
function statutify(value) {
    return { status: value };
}

var getTasks = function(params) {
    if (params.status.constructor === Array) {
        var newParams = params.status.map(statutify);
        console.log(newParams);
    }
    // ...
};
```

Or, it can't hurt to learn something about other libraries like @voithos suggests.